# do ads on iAd banners automatically come?

Tags: xcode, ios, iad

are ads picked up from a signal or do i have to put the ads in. I have the test advertisment working so now what? Do the ads generate themselves?

Answer (score 2):

If you can see the test ads then everything is working. When you publish on the App Store your users will see real adverts.